# Parsing Datatable to XML Document

Tags: asp.net, datatable

I would like to write a method to convert a asp.net datatable into XML document. What is the best way to achieve it? Apologize it it is very basic question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `"WriteXml"` method to convert your datatable into XML document.

Example:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Product");
 DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();
 dc.ColumnName = "ProductID";
 dc.DataType = typeof(int);
 dt.Columns.Add(dc);

 DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn();
 dc2.ColumnName = "ProductName";
 dc2.DataType = typeof(string);
 dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
 dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", "CShap In Depth By Jon Skeet" })
 dt.WriteXml("{path to save your xml file}\\documentname.xml");
```

But still you want extension method you can use the following sample code (Not Tested)

(taken from http://www.extensionmethod.net/csharp/datatable/toxml )

```
public static XDocument ToXmlDocument(this DataTable dataTable, string rootName)
        {
            var XmlDocument = new XDocument
            {
                Declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "")
            };
            XmlDocument.Add(new XElement(rootName));
            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                XElement element = null;
                if (dataTable.TableName != null)
                {
                   element = new XElement(dataTable.TableName);
                }
                foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
                {
                    element.Add(new
                XElement(column.ColumnName, row[column].ToString().Trim(' ')));
                }
                if (XmlDocument.Root != null) XmlDocument.Root.Add(element);
            }

            return XmlDocument;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at using [DataTable.WriteXml Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml.aspx)

> Writes the current contents of the DataTable as XML.

More specifically the overloads using [XmlWriteMode Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.xmlwritemode.aspx)

Using the option `WriteSchema`

> Writes the current contents of the DataSet as XML data with the
>   relational structure as inline XSD schema. If the DataSet has only a
>   schema with no data, only the inline schema is written. If the DataSet
>   does not have a current schema, nothing is written.